# Does all instances (Parellelism) of Async I/O Operator share the same Broadcast State

Tags: apache-flink

To know whether broadcast state is shared among all the instances of an Operator.

Operator can be anything, but in my case it is Async I/O Operator.

Comment: I don't believe the Async I/O operator is designed to allow for broadcast state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of an operator handling broadcast state receives and potentially stores its own copy of that state (and each instance independently checkpoints its broadcast state). If there are multiple sources of broadcast state, the order of processing those broadcast streams in downstream operators is non-deterministic, which could lead to inconsistencies among the various instances.

Comment: We were able to use Broadcast State in Async I/O Operator. The reason we are using state is because we wanted to have a state before making an external API call if we already have the data

Comment: I'm skeptical about that working as intended. I'd love to see how you have that set up.

Comment: by implementing CheckpointedFunction.

sample code:
MyRichAsyncFunction extends RichAsyncFunction<Source, Target> implements CheckpointedFunction

so by implementing CheckpointedFunction, I am getting access to Operator State, by using the below code.

 state= functionInitializationContext
                .getOperatorStateStore()
                .getBroadcastState(new MapStateDescriptor<>("state",
                        BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Map<String, Object>>() {
                        })));

Comment: That's kind of what I expected. Each instance will operate completely independently, which might not be what you were after (the instances won't share the state), and if you ever rescale, the outcome could be problematic: Scaling in will result in data loss, scaling out will result in duplication. I don't see much advantage to this over just keeping a cache that isn't in Flink state.

Comment: The problems I mentioned are why Flink doesn't offer MapState as operator state -- there's no way to rescale it.

Comment: could you explain "just keeping a cache", can we use some kind of Cache (maybe provided by some Java library or in-memory Java Map) in Flink Operator?

so all instances of Operator refer to the same cache.

Comment: I'm not aware of any reasonable way to have an in-memory cache that all instances of an operator will use (Flink is designed so that the instances share nothing). Broadcast state won't do that for you, nor will Guava Cache, which is an example of what I had in mind when I spoke of "just keeping a cache".